# Disable Focus Visual Effects UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp

I want to disable the focus visual effects on TextBox in my UWP app.

What I've tried:

```
<TextBox x:Name="CodigoTextBox"
                 Text ="{x:Bind Codigo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 MinWidth="150"
                 BorderThickness="0"
                 IsFocusEngagementEnabled="False"
                 FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="Transparent"
                 FocusVisualPrimaryThickness="0"
                 FocusVisualSecondaryBrush="Transparent"
                 FocusVisualSecondaryThickness="0"
                 IsFocusEngaged="False"
                 FocusVisualMargin="0"
                 AllowFocusOnInteraction="True"/>
```

I want to do this because I'm creating an UserControl where I'll have a Combobox and a textbox inside a grid where I just want the outer borders to be visible.

Comment: The common way to change a behavior of control is to edit its style. @mm8's answer is a good example and you could have a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to design mode in Visual Studio, right-click on the `TextBox` and choose Edit Template->Edit a Copy.

This will copy the default template into your XAML markup. You can then simply comment out the "Focused" `VisualState`.

Here is a fully working example:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForeground}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackground}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlSelectionHighlightColor}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}"/>
            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{ThemeResource IsApplicationFocusVisualKindReveal}"/>
            <Setter Property="ContextFlyout" Value="{StaticResource TextControlCommandBarContextFlyout}"/>
            <Setter Property="SelectionFlyout" Value="{StaticResource TextControlCommandBarSelectionFlyout}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <Style x:Name="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                <Grid x:Name="ButtonLayoutGrid" Background="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackground}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                                      BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrush}">
                                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackgroundPressed}"/>
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                                                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0"/>
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </VisualState>
                                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    <TextBlock x:Name="GlyphElement" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" FontStyle="Normal" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForeground}" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="&#xE10A;" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundDisabled}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushDisabled}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundDisabled}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundDisabled}}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundPointerOver}}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <!--<VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundFocused}}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundFocused}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushFocused}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundFocused}"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>-->
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Normal" Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForeground}" Margin="{ThemeResource TextBoxTopHeaderMargin}" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed" x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"/>
                            <Border x:Name="BorderElement" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True" MinHeight="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" MinWidth="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}" IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsTabStop="False" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}" ZoomMode="Disabled"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}"/>
                            <Button x:Name="DeleteButton" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" IsTabStop="False" MinWidth="34" Margin="{ThemeResource HelperButtonThemePadding}" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="DescriptionPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Content="{TemplateBinding Description}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlDescriptionTextForegroundBrush}" Grid.Row="2" x:Load="False"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: I'm using UWP with WINUI3, I cant even see the object properties window, thank you for the example, that helped me a lot.